# How to parse a BIG JSON (45MB) with kotlinx.serialization recursively/incrementally

Tags: android, json, kotlin, deserialization

I'm doing an app for Android that has to parse very big JSON files. The problem is that parsing the hole JSON file at once takes a lot of RAM memory usage and I don't want that (OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 92164736 byte allocation with 34470928 free bytes and 32MB until OOM, target footprint 268435456, growth limit 268435456" (VmSize 31806868 kB))

I searched and also asked to ChatGPT but I wasn't able...

I wanted a low usage of RAM but it takes like 520MB a 45MB JSON file.

[ChatGPT solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJYvm.png) but don't work.

Comment: Can you add your code so we can exactly figure out .. otherwise there will be many suggestions to manage it in answers

Comment: You might want to open an issue in [kotlinx.serialization's repo](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues)